# Would allowing all Unearthed Arcana create rules problems?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana

I’m thinking of running a campaign where the players don’t have books and I wanted to recommend that they use the SRD until then, but also use any Unearthed Arcana material from Wizards’ site if they wanted.

Would allowing all Unearthed Arcana material create any balance problems or fundamental rule contradictions?

The main reasons being would be to allow players to use free material without worrying about buying books just yet, but also having available more interesting stuff to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close as *needs more focus*. There is too much material here for us to be able to give you a good answer. I suggest going to your players, finding out which UA options they want, and then coming back with those. This way we have a much smaller set of options to consider. Right now, it is far too broad.

Comment: Anyway, welcome to RPG.se! If you haven't already, take our [tour]. We love helping, and are probably well equipped to hand questions *like* this, but its too much to ask for someone to consider the entire body of Unearthed Arcana, when 90% if will not be used.

Comment: I don't see how this is broad, yes there is a lot of UA, but this is certainly something someone here can answer as it stands. The OP doesn't ask for a breakdown of it all, just a yes/no and a bit of why.

Comment: @SeriousBri Right, an answer doesn't have to show a breakdown of all the material, but a correct answer would at least need to have considered interaction between all of the relevant UA material to make an assessment.

Comment: How familiar are you with the rules personally?

Comment: Actually, it seemed to me a nice question. You may improve it by including further details, such as how much experienced your players are (if they are completely new to DnD or to RPGs, or if they already played this kind of games in the past), if you already have been a DM, and so on. This may help to receive more tailored answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Unearthed Arcana](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana) is a collection of spells, subclasses, feats and other game material that still have to be tested: it may happen that some of those would be too powerful, make an unbalanced game or create some contradiction with basic rules.

The material in [SRD](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) is pretty vast and offers a wide range of choices. If you are going to run a campaign with inexperienced players, the available options in SRD allow to comprehend the game mechanics and, more important, to have a lot of fun, even without the brand new and cool material from UA. Once your players are more familiar with the game mechanics, you may start to introduce some options from UA, even I strongly suggest to firstly employ the [PHB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb).  Of course, another option is to use UA material from the beginning and playtest it during your campaign, .

In both cases, you may say to your players that you are allowing them to use UA material, but if you see that one particular option is unbalancing the game or enter in conflict with some basic rule you will backtrack and stop employing that.

---

As personal experience, once one of the player in the campaign that I am DMing asked if its character could use this [spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-bestial-spirit-ua): it looked to me too powerful at the level they were at time, hence I decided to not include that spell in my game.

Answer (score -2):

## Yes, this will create balance problems, though probably not contradicting rule problems.

In terms of rules, the creators of UA material are also the creators of the official material, and know how the rules of the game work.  They are careful in their choice of words, and will be sure to not cause a confusion of rules overlapping.  Any contradictions that do come up however would be left to be resolved by the DM.

At the start of every [*Unearthed Arcana*](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_102620_Subclasses05.pdf) (linked to the most recent at time of this post), there is a quick write up about the nature of this playtest material:

> The material in this article is presented for playtesting
> and to spark your imagination. These game mechanics
> are in draft form, usable in your campaign but not
> refined by full game design and editing. They aren’t
> officially part of the game and aren’t permitted in D&D
> Adventurers League events.

I assume you are not running an Adventurers League story, so you don't have to worry about that.

> If we decide to make this material official, it will be
> refined based on your feedback, and then it will appear
> in a D&D book

I would take this to omit any Unearthed Arcana that have since been printed in later released books, like the subclasses in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* or the feats in the upcoming *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything.*  Otherwise you may have players taking the UA version of the material that has objectively better features - higher numbers, more abilities, etc. - then what is officially published.

> The character options you read here might be more
> or less powerful than options in the Player’s
> Handbook. If a design survives playtesting, we adjust
> its power to the desirable level before official
> publication

This is why UA is most frequently not allowed, as due to its nature of being untested, it is hard to be sure what is or is not balanced.  Most DMs are not going to want a player to be too powerful, or the other players will feel neglected; same goes for being an underwhelming UA, as the player will be fast to get bored.  Though at a DMs discretion these can be fun changes to the game and welcome additions.

> In early playtests such as this, character options are
> rarely tuned for multiclassing. We are nonetheless
> interested in multiclass-related feedback, accounting
> for it if we finalize the design for publication.

Here's where things can get really weird.  Multiclassing UA with other UA material, or with the optional materials like feats, can really have some strange and powerful results. The ability to multiclass also so widens the pool of options for your characters that it is exceptionally hard to predict what could happen when different things are mixed together.

### An Example UA Abusing Build

This will be a 5th level Variant Human multiclassing [UA Mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) with one level in Fighter.  Wielding a Glaive (from the martial weapon proficiency gained from the level in fighter), in the Order of the Immortal focusing on Giant Growth, *the character would have a melee weapon reach of 15 feet*.  Combine this with the [UA Tunnel Fighter](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/02_UA_Underdark_Characters.pdf) fighting style, and the [Sentinel and Polearm Master feats](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/players-handbook#feats) (one gained from being the Variant human, the other gained from the 4th level in Mystic), the character would be able to make an opportunity attack against any creature that moves into the 15 feet radius around them - which would halt the creatures movement - every single turn for the round, at the **cost of a bonus action**.  This is just one example, and very likely not the craziest.

### But...

What's most important is that the table is having fun!  If the players want to create strange and powerful builds, and the DM is okay with balancing around them, then open the floodgates.  This may mean one character is stronger or weaker than the others, but there are ways to buff and nerf characters, or play to their strengths, that will ensure all the people at the table are still having a good time.

Comment: Older UA articles on subclasses/classes used to also say they are NOT tuned for multiclassing. THat presents a potential rules interaction, no? I am not familiar enough with ALL of the UA (as currently requested), but if you're going to say no rules interactions, you should be sure about that.

Comment: Regarding your example, if they only have access to the SRD and UA that would not include Sentinel or Polearm Master feats. Not saying there aren't OP combinations, just pointing out this specific case.